# Splunk API : Failed to connect host. Connection refused

Tags: curl, splunk

I am trying to connect `Splunk` using command line. Below is my code as per documentation -

```
curl --get -k -u username:password -d "output_
mode=csv" -d "count=5" https://api.nr5b-yk5q.data.splunkstorm.com:8089/servicesN
S/scottwedeking/search/search/jobs/1310082457.10/results
```

But I am getting error :

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to api.nr5b-yk5q.data.splunkstorm.com port 8089: Con
nection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be attempting to access a [Splunk Enterprise REST Endpoint](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.1.1/RESTAPI/RESTsearch#search.2Fjobs.2F.7Bsearch_id.7D). However, Splunk Storm is not Splunk Enterprise, and those [APIs don't seem to be available currently on this product](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Storm/latest/User/UseStormsRESTAPI).

<strike>Additionally, you seem to be attempting to connect to `api.nr5b-yk5q.data.splunkstorm.com`. Which documentation said to connect there exactly?</strike> (EDIT: I found it, generating code to send data via the API will use an endpoint like the one listed above.) Port 8089 does not seem to be open, but port 443 does (the Storm REST API doc above, says the endpoint should be `https://api.splunkstorm.com/` and both `api.splunkstorm.com` and your host seem to be aliases to the same AWS load balancers.) You can verify this using dig or some other DNS tool.